# flask: post data after insert, delete and update in database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to post data to a target url after insertion, updation and deletion in a model in flask like [rest-hooks](https://github.com/zapier/django-rest-hooks) in django. for now i have only found signal events of flask-sqlalchemy like below:

```
@event.listens_for(MyModel, 'after_insert')
def do_stuff(mapper, connection, target):
```

So how to do this in flask like we do using rest-hooks in Django or is there any other library which i can use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like you already have it figured out. your `do_stuff` method will be triggered after an insert. You can do the same with `'after_update'` and `'after_delete'`. Or is your question about how to make a post request in python? For that you can use requests, for example (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: @AArias
yeah, i have figured this out but i also want to know if there is a library like rest-hooks in flask too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your REST end-point where you want to POST to is in the same flask application. It is a good practice to separate out the business logic in your REST end-points and share the code across your whole application.

In my case, I usually create separate py files (called them services) and move the business logic there:

```
# inventory_services.py

def delete_item(id, data):
    pass
    # ... business logic here
```

Then call this method from your REST end-point where you POST data to:

```
from inventory_services import delete_item

@api.route('/inventory/delete-item', methods=['POST'])
def delete_item_api():
    posted_data = request.get_json()
    delete_item(posted_data.id, posted_data.data)
```

Use the same service methods in your SQL Alchemy hook methods:

```
from inventory_services import delete_item

@event.listens_for(MyModel, 'after_insert')
def do_stuff(mapper, connection, target):
    delete_item(id, data)
```

The basic idea here is to move the code in your api methods to other plain functions so that they will be accessible across your whole application.